# Name of a device for keeping connectors of cables together

Tags: hardware-rec

I have a few cables which I connect and disconnect to a laptop of mine, always together. I want to force the ends of these cables - the connectors and a bit of slack cable length - to not come apart.

Naturally, I can tie (pairs of) them together, but what I would really like is some piece of hard material which has several cylindrical holes for each of these cables to go through - preferably such that doesn't let the cables detach due to tugging and pulling, only by releasing some latch.

Now, I'm not asking for a recommendation of something to buy. What I'm trying to figure out is what would be the *name* of such a device - i.e. what do I use as a search key when I look for actual products. (I'm not a native English speaker.)

Sketch of how this might look like (sorry, it's super-ugly):

[image]

PS - I realize I might instead, be able to use something like a USB-C-connected hub, and that is fine and good, but not what I'm asking about.

Comment: Something like this? https://www.amazon.co.uk/3-Pack-Desktop-Organizer-Management-Charging/dp/B07T72KRVX/ref=sr_1_8?keywords=cable+management&qid=1677530701&sr=8-8

Comment: Or this https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/265582207365?

Comment: @DavidPostill: Sketch added. The linked items won't do, because with a bit of tugging, the cables will be pulled out of the... grooves, or channels, I guess we could call them.

Comment: "cable tidy tube"

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Management-Organisers-Multipurpose-Adhesive-Ethernet/dp/B07RQCXCR2?th=1 includes https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51AWEnSrCLL._AC_.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Some relevant names based on links to not-quite-what I'm looking for:

- "cable clip"
- "cable manager"
- "cable holder"
- "cable organizer"

None very exact, but they're useful. Thanks @DavidPostill.

I also found [this thing](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004550863005.html) which is kind of close to what I'm looking for:

[image]

... and it's called "Cable Organizer Cord Management Wire Holder Flexible USB Cable Winder Tidy Silicone Clips For Mouse Keyboard Earphone Protector". Hmm.

Comment: That's standard AliExpess automated translation chaos. But "cable organizer" is probably your best bet for looking for a product like this and if it exists then Chinese stores are the best bet indeed.

Comment: Be careful, I purchased a similar one(not this one), the double side sticky lasted about 3 weeks, then it fell off the desk in a curl.  I have had more success with single cable ones.

Comment: @RohitGupta: Thanks for the heads-up, I'm not counting on those things sticking too well, but if the plastic doesn't break, that's good enough :-)